# Going from 9.5.1 to 10.0.1 keep getting same error message regarding Twig

Tags: 10

I've tried going to 10.0.1 using Composer and then tried updating to 10.0.1 and get the same error message....

The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

Error: Class "Twig_Extension" not found in include() (line 12 of /home/customer/www/wiulibraries.org/public_html/video1/modules/entity_embed/src/Twig/EntityEmbedTwigExtension.php).

include() (Line: 571)
Composer\Autoload\includeFile('/home/customer/www/wiulibraries.org/public_html/video1/modules/entity_embed/src/Twig/EntityEmbedTwigExtension.php') (Line: 428)
Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass('Drupal\entity_embed\Twig\EntityEmbedTwigExtension')
is_subclass_of('Drupal\entity_embed\Twig\EntityEmbedTwigExtension', 'Twig\Extension\ExtensionInterface') (Line: 181)
Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\Compiler\TaggedHandlersPass->processServiceCollectorPass(Array, 'twig', Object) (Line: 116)
Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\Compiler\TaggedHandlersPass->process(Object) (Line: 73)
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\Compiler->compile(Object) (Line: 721)
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->compile() (Line: 1307)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->compileContainer() (Line: 911)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->initializeContainer() (Line: 477)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->boot() (Line: 679)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)

Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers :) What does `composer info drupal/entity_embed | grep drupal/core` tell you? If you have a D10 compatible version of the module you should see something similar to `drupal/core ^9 || ^10`

Comment: Is your currently versions of all modules are compatible with newest? Are you shure? During the installation the newest version should show all issue. Im getting a full of errors after when my old 9 version is not compatible in 100% with 10. I musted returned to 9, fix it (in many cases turn off the ceasaed modules) and try to install 10. Finally Iam stay in 9.

Comment: it says          drupal/core ^9.3 || ^10

Comment: it says         I

 Package "drupal/entity_embed" not found, try using --available   then if I add --available it says    ^9.3 || ^10

Comment: Please confirm the precise version of entity_embed installed. Looking at the project page, it isn't clear whether the released version of the module is fully prepared for Drupal 10.

Comment: The dev version is @cilefen. KAGmalpass, if the module isn't installed in composer, the question becomes how is it in the codebase and why? The fact that the path isn't `modules/contrib` might suggest you've installed it manually, in which case you either need to update it to the dev version manually, or delete it, then require it with composer and clear cache a couple of times so the system picks it up from the new path under contrib

Answer (score 2):

You must use [the most current dev version of entity_embed](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_embed/releases/8.x-1.x-dev) because the released version, 8.x-1.3, uses the old Twig_Extension.

A [commit in December 2022](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/entity_embed/-/commit/f41e8a4662dfa9dfc1e7c7bd20a7173f9a231352#aef81e13274458f8ee355356c52c3694b7be35e3_13_14) removed the usage of Twig_Extension but this has not yet been released.